# Algorithm for converting list of predefined strings into an array of integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linear-algebra

I have a list of strings (file) with hundreds of thousands elements.
All strings are of length 10.

Each string can have one of 58 fixed values.

List fragment example:

```
NORMAL    
NORMAL    
NORMAL    
NORMAL    
NORMAL    
HUNT_GROUP
CALL_TRANS
RING_BACK 
CALL_TRANS
HUNT_GROUP
NORMAL    
NORMAL    
FWD_NOREPL
NORMAL    
HUNT_GROUP
CALL_TRANS
RING_BACK 
NORMAL    
CALL_TRANS
HUNT_GROUP
HUNT_GROUP
NORMAL    
HUNT_GROUP
HUNT_GROUP
CALL_TRANS
HUNT_GROUP
HUNT_GROUP
CALL_TRANS
RING_BACK 
CALL_TRANS
NORMAL    
FWD_UNCOND
```

I want to convert string values into integers, e.g. NORMAL -> 1, CALL_TRANS -> 3, RING_BACK -> 19, HUNT_GROUP -> 11 and so on, in documented accordance.

First idea of using operator CASE works extremely slow:

```
case S of
  'NORMAL    ': I:=1;
  'CALL_TRANS': I:=3;
  'RING_BACK ': I:=19;
  'HUNT_GROUP': I:=11;
  'FWD_NOREPL': I:=7;
  'FWD_UNCOND': I:=6;
  'FWD_BUSY  ': I:=5;
  . . .
end;
```

The same with the loop (A: array[0..57] of string[10], containing all possible values):

```
for J:=0 to 57 do 
  if S=A[J] then begin
    I:=J;
    break;
  end;
```

A bit better result if the list of strings is preprocessed, the most frequent values placed at the beginning of CASE operator or A array.

I expect that this task is a well-known one, having a nice solution. Though I can't find it...

Some ideas.

Comparing the whole strings is slow. Iterating on all 58 values is slow.

Let's use first character of a string S as an index of array A1[A..Z] of integer, filled in a special manner, explained later.

Then if S='FWD_NOREPL', then S[1]='F' and A1[F]=5.

Thus we have narrowed the list of possible values, because only 3 strings starts with 'F'.
To finally determine the string, we should check 5th string character, because it is not the same for 3 ones.

Array A1 is a predefined constant and contain the number of string character to be checked next A1[F]=5.

If S[1]='F', then S[5] can be either 'N', 'U' or 'B'. For S='FWD_NOREPL' S[5]='N'. Now the string is 100% determined by 2 characters.

So A1 gives an index, which character to examine next.

A2[A..Z] contains final integer values for conversion: A2[N]=7, A2[U]=6, A2[B]=5.

```
         1
1234567890
FWD_NOREPL   -> 7
FWD_UNCOND   -> 6
FWD_BUSY     -> 5
|
S[1]=F
A1[F]=5
S[5]=N
A2[N]=7
```

So the problem is to build A1 and A2 in a clever deterministic way. I expect there should be a known solution for this task, too.

Finally we do not need to compare strings and iterate over 58 values.

Two short "jumps" over indexes provide necessary values. This should be very fast.

List of 58 strings of length 10 looks like a 10x58 matrix. Maybe algebra can help?

Question is about coming up with a good algorithm. It is not specific to a any programming language. Though I'm more common with Pascal (Lazarus).

Comment: What you’re looking for is known as a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). There are libraries to generate them for a given set of keys, such as gperf.

Comment: As the list is small, you may compute CRC16 for many "polynomial_ bit_strings",i.e. an int16  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), until one polynom provides different CRC for all items in the list. Once done, create a 64 K table T where T[CRC(word)] = Index_of_word_in the_ list.